# Please how can i meanwhile the user touching the screen With one finger i want the user able to start onClick button function With the other finger

Tags: android-studio

app for baby. so i need that the button will be able to work meanwhile the baby touching the screen in Other Places

that is the xml code taht i have now

```xml
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/nextId2" android:layout_width="61dp" 
    android:layout_height="61dp" android:onClick="nextactivity" 
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" 
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" 
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.905" 
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" 
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.071" app:srcCompat="@drawable/home" />
```

Comment: Woah there.  I see no code here...

Comment: <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/nextId2"
        android:layout_width="61dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:onClick="nextactivity"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.905"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.071"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/home" />

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `android:splitMotionEvents`.  However, this would need to be set in the parent to this button and not in the button itself.  Here is an example with a `LinearLayout`:

```xml
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:splitMotionEvents="true" >

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/nextId2" android:layout_width="61dp" 
        android:layout_height="61dp" android:onClick="nextactivity" 
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" 
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" 
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.905" 
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" 
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.071" app:srcCompat="@drawable/home" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This option can also be set in the code with the `setMotionEventSplittingEnabled` function.  [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup#attr_android:splitMotionEvents) is some more information about this option.